# What genre did Arthur Hailey's works belong to?

Tags: terminology, genre

I'm trying to find fiction works where the world of a story is an organization of certain kind (an airport, a bank, an automobile factory etc.). The most prominent writer in this genre is [Arthur Hailey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Hailey). I want to find more and more recent books like that.

What is this genre called in the English-speaking world?

**My research**

The [Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD) suggests the name *occupational novel*. However, when I look for it at [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/occupational-novel), I only find non-fiction books (biographies, mostly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2004/nov/27/guardianobituaries.books) refers to the Hailey as a germinator of the "factional" genre.

> The fruit of diligent research, which in his long (seldom under
>   500-page) novels was sometimes dispensed in barely digested globules,
>   his work laid the groundwork for the "factional" genre, ***which uses
>   authentic backgrounds as a backcloth for human stereotypes***. Faction
>   was later employed by many other writers of topical appeal, including
>   Frederick Forsyth and Jeffrey Archer.

The term "factional" is a portmanteau of "fact" and 'fiction" [see Non-Fiction novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fiction_novel).